# How do I create a DOCTYPE with ENTITIES in python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml

I wish to create some gdml with ENTITIES as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE gdml [
<!ENTITY define SYSTEM "define.xml">
<!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materials.xml">
<!ENTITY solids SYSTEM "fredF4-solids.xml">
<!ENTITY structure SYSTEM "fredF4-structure.xml">
]>
```

I have created a string

```
docString ='<!DOCTYPE gdml [<!ENTITY define SYSTEM "define.xml"><!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materials.xml"><!ENTITY solids SYSTEM "fredF4-solids.xml"><!ENTITY structure SYSTEM "fredF4-structure.xml">]>'
```

But if I code elem = ET.fromstring(docString)

I get an error and the same for

```
  elem = ET.XML(docString)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3216, in lxml.etree.XML
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1896, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1777, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1082, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 615, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 654, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  <class 'lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError'>: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 189    (<string>, line 1)
```

I should point out I am trying to add the !DOCTYPE info as part of a GDML file which currently is successfully initially declared with

```
  !NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  location_attribute = '{%s}noNameSpaceSchemaLocation' % NS
  gdml = ET.Element('gdml',attrib={location_attribute: 'http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd'})
```

Comment: You need a root element in order for it to be XML. Right now you just have the prolog (doctype declaration).

Comment: Tried changing docString to<gdml><!DOCTYPE gdml [<!ENTITY define SYSTEM "define.xml"><!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materials.xml"><!ENTITY solids SYSTEM "fred3-solids.xml"><!ENTITY structure SYSTEM "fred3-structure.xml">]></gdml>

But get error
: StartTag: invalid element name, line 1, column 8 (<string>, line 1)

Comment: Okay change the string to 
<!DOCTYPE gdml [<!ENTITY define SYSTEM "define.xml"><!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materials.xml"><!ENTITY solids SYSTEM "fred7-solids.xml"><!ENTITY structure SYSTEM "fred7-structure.xml">]><gdml></gdml>

And it works but Ideally would like to specify schema with ET.Element rather that have to also set up with a text string,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the `doctype` arg in either the [`tostring()` function](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) or the [`write()` method](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write).

Examples...

```py
etree.tostring(gdml, doctype=docString).decode()
```

or

```py
etree.ElementTree(gdml).write("output.xml", doctype=docString)
```

Comment: That is neater, thought there must be such a solution.

Comment: Thought that was done, by checkmark I assume you mean the Green tick

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel

I managed to add the DocString without the gdml elements by

```
  !NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  location_attribute = '{%s}noNameSpaceSchemaLocation' % NS
  gdml = ET.Element('gdml',attrib={location_attribute: 'http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd'})
```

and

```
  docString += ET.tostring(gdml).decode("UTF-8"))
  gdml = ET.fromstring(docString.encode("UTF-8"))
```